# SQL Server - Login failed for user (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, sql-server-2019

I have written code using JDBC to create registration page in Android Studio. I create database in SQL Server 2019. In addition I tried to connect from the code to MSSQL database and insert values, but while I run the app I'm getting the error:

> login failed for user.

I have examined many options that can cause this error and I fixed them. For example: The server authentication is SQL Server authentication,the TCP option at the server is enabled, I have the relevant permissions of the user, also I check the if the firewall is the cause for this error. However, I continue to receive the error.

The connection class:

```
public class ConnectionClass {
    public static String ip= "***.***.*.*:1433"; //
    public static String user_name ="****";
    public static String password = "****";
    public static String database = "tests";
}
```

The Registeration class:

```
EditText email;
    EditText password;
    EditText confirmPassword;
    Button sign_up;
    EditText name;
    Connection connection1;
    Statement statement;
    TextView status;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sign_up_parent);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextEmailAddress2);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);
        confirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword2);
        sign_up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        name =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword3);
        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

        sign_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new ParentSignUp.registerUser().execute("");
            }
        });

    }



    public class registerUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        String z ="";
        Boolean isSuccess = false;

        public registerUser() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            status.setText("Sending Data to Database");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            name.setText("");
            email.setText("");
            password.setText("");
            confirmPassword.setText("");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                connection1 = connection_class(ConnectionClass.user_name.toString(), ConnectionClass.password.toString(),
                        ConnectionClass.database.toString(), ConnectionClass.ip.toString());
                if (connection1 == null) {
                    z = "Check Internet Connection";

                }
                else {
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO test (name,password, email) VALUES ('example', 'example', 'example')";
                    statement = connection1.createStatement();
                    statement.executeUpdate(sql);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                isSuccess = false;
                z = e.getMessage();

            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection connection_class (String user, String password, String database, String server) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection connection = null;
        String connectionUrl = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            connectionUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server + "/" + database + ";user=" + user + ";"+"password=" + password + ";";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("SQL Connection Error : ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return connection;

    }
```

Comment: Check the SQL Server logs; can you see the authentication failure there? If so, what is the error (as the errors returned to the application are intentionally vague)? If not, then the connection is never reaching the SQL Server instance.

Comment: If you get "Login Failed" then you are connecting to the SQL server....  Are you sure your connection string is correct? Don't you have to specift Database=MyDBName ?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I don't see the authentication failure in SQL Server log. There are some messages that I don't quite understand what they are saying. I think the connection string is correct.